# List of used files in the Docker context

Tags: docker

Let's say I got a repository with multiple projects structured like this:

```
Root
 ├── bar
 │   ├── Dockerfile
 │   └── index.js
 ├── baz
 │   ├── Dockerfile
 │   └── index.js
 ├── foo
 │   ├── Dockerfile
 │   └── index.js
 └── shared
     └── utils.js
     └── shared.js
```

The `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` projects share some libraries in the `shared` folder. Currently, I'm sending the root folder as `context` to build these  three Docker images to include the `shared` folder.

To increase build time and reduce deployment time of my Docker images, I need to get the minimum size of `context` sent to these images.

In order to do so, I plan on making a temporary folder for each images that will be used as `context`. Thing is, I need to know which shared files are used by each images.

In this example, its quite simple because there is few shared files and few projects. But in reality, there are hundreds of shared files and about 20 projects, and I don't want to check which shared files are used by which projects.

Here is an example of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:boron

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package.json
RUN yarn

COPY . .

RUN yarn release

CMD node release/server.js
```

And I build the Docker image with:

```
docker build -t foo:latest ..
```

Note the `..` that point to the `Root` folder. This will result in all the shared files sent to the context, even those that are not needed.

Is there an easy way to know which files of the sent `context` to Docker are used by it and which are not?

Comment: Maybe you could use this https://github.com/pwaller/docker-show-context

Comment: You cannot expect this from Docker, you need a tool which will create temporary directory for you and use that to build the docker image. You can try makefile if you have written one before.

Comment: @vedarthk I'm not looking for a tool to provide a specific context, I'm looking for a way to know which files of the context are required for an image Docker to successfully run.

Comment: @Erazihel sorry I misinterpreted your question. I am not sure if any tool related to docker can find the files, you can do that if there a tool which constantly monitors file I/O in the container (LXC) while building. But you can try and see if you build tool can output the used files which can then be used to make future builds faster.

Comment: For each file in shared, grep for that file in each file of each project?

Comment: @Erazihel it should be as easy as read the Dockerfile, searching for COPY or ADD. What is the issue with that?

Comment: @Robert Not every copied or added files are used by Docker, that's the issue.

Comment: @Erazihel, ok! I think that you should ask for files that the **application** uses. I have an idea

Comment: @Erazihel So you want the files relating to your server app to be the only files present for your build? Do the dockerfiles contain information about which packages it needs? What official image is your image building from or What OS if any?

Comment: @Jouster500 Dockerfiles do not contain information about which packages they need. I'm using the `node:boron` image.

Comment: @Erazihel do you have a link to the image on the docker hub? Why does the entire root directory need to be passed if the only directory you need to reference is the shared directory?

Comment: @Erazihel If I'm interpreting your question and steps correctly, you want to build an image of one of the projects that contains all these other images which inextricably link to all required dependencies. I would assume you do not know exactly what dependencies are needed by each individual image as then that would indicate you are misusing your overall dockerfile, which is meant to explicitly build an app accordingly (Also assuming unix/linux build). Good practice requires your dockerfiles to **EXPLICITLY** get its dependency, instead of auto-resolving it, but you prefer the latter, correct?

Comment: @Jouster500 yes I prefer the correct because the projects are huge and I simply cannot investigate which files is required for which Docker image. That's why I'm looking for something to tell me what file are used so I can **EXPLICITLY** get the correct dependencies for the images :p

Comment: @Erazihel have you solved the issue by some way?

Comment: Hey @Robert, kinda busy for the moment, I'll try all the solutions when I'll have some free time

Comment: the simplest thing, and fastest build is to build a base image with your shared files, and use that as a base for all your dependent projects. each image can be built in its own folder/context without all the other ones, making the context minimum and speed up the build. see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Before I begin, let me clear up a few misconceptions and define some terminology for users new and old. First off, **docker images** are more or less snapshots of a containers configurations. Everything from filesystems to network configurations are contained within an image and can be used to quickly create new instances (containers) of said image.

**Containers** are running instances of a particular image and that is where all the magic happens. Docker containers can be viewed as tiny virtual machines, but unlike virtual machines, the system resources are unanimously shared and has a few other features that VM's do not readily have. [You can get more information about this in another stack overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine?rq=1)

**Building an image** is either done by saving a container (`docker commit *container* *repoTag*`) or by building from a **Dockerfile** which is automated build instructions as if you were to make changes to a container yourself. It also gives end users a running "Transaction" of all the commands needed to get your app running.

> To decrease build time ... of my Docker images

Correct me if I am wrong, but it would seem that you are trying to build your image for each new container. Docker images are only needed to spin up a container. Yes, building them does take a while especially for dockerfiles, but once they *are* built, it really takes a trivial amount of time to spin up a container with your desired app which is really all you need. Again, **docker images are save states of previous container configurations, and loading a save state does not and should not consume a lot of time,** so you really shouldn't be concerned with a dockerfiles build time.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Despite this, *working to decrease a Dockerfiles build time and containers end file size is still a valid question* and turning to automated dependency resolutions is a common approach. In fact, [I asked a similar question nearly 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653851/how-to-deploy-a-self-building-docker-image-to-make-changes-to-itself-in-respect), so it may possess some information that can aid in this endeavor. 
However...

> To decrease build time and reduce deployment time of my Docker images, I need to get the minimum size of context sent to these images.

To which Taco, a person who answered my earlier question, would have replied

> Docker isn't going to offer you painless builds. Docker doesn't know what you want.

Yes, it certainly would be less of a hassle if Docker knew what you wanted from the get-go but the fact remains that ***you need to tell it exactly what you want if you are aiming for it to build with the best size and best time***. However there is more than one way to obtain the best build time and/or build size.

- One blatantly obvious one, as Andreas Wederbrand has mentioned in
  this very same post, that you could get the apps logs from a previous
  run to verify what it does or doesnt need. Suppose you did build one 
  of your project apps by dumping all possible dependencies into it.
  You could systematically take out all dependencies, run the app,
  check for failure in its logs, add a dependency, check for output
  difference. If output is the same, remove failed dependency,
  otherwise keep the dependency.

If I wrote this particular command in a dockerfile it may go a little something like this, assuming the container is built from a linux system:

```
#ASSUMING LINUX CONTAINER!
...
WORKDIR path/to/place/project
RUN mkdir dependencyTemp
COPY path/to/project/and/dependencies/ .
#Next part is written in pseudo code for the time being
RUN move all dependencies to dependencyTemp \
   && run app and store state and logs\
   && while [$appState != running]; do {\
   add dependency to folder && run app and store state and logs \
   if [$logsOriginal == $logsNew]; then remove dependency from folder \
   else keep dependency && logsOriginal = logsNew fi}
```

This however is terribly inefficient as you are starting and stopping your application internally to find the dependencies needed for your app resulting in a terribly long build time. True, it would somewhat counter the issue of finding the dependencies yourself and reduce some size, but It may not work 100% of the time and its probably going to take less time for you to find what dependencies are needed to run your app as opposed to designing the code to escape that gap.

- Another solution/alternative, albeit more complicated, is to [link
  containers via networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/). Networking containers has remained a
  challenge for me, but its straightforward in what you would want it
  to accomplish with it. Say you spin up 3 containers, 2 of which are
  projects, the other a dependency container. Through the network, one
  container can reference the dependency container and obtain all needed dependencies similar to your current setup. Unlike yours however, the dependencies are not located on the app which means your other apps can be built with bare minimum size and time.

However, should the dependency container go down, then the other apps would go down as well which may not result in a stable system for the long run. Additionally you would have to stop and start the every container every time you needed to add a new dependency or project.

- Lastly, if your containers are going to be kept locally you could
  look into [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#add-a-data-volume). Volumes are a nifty way of mounting file systems
  to active containers so applications within the containers can
  reference files that are not explicitly there. This translates to a
  more elegant docker build as all dependencies can legitimately be
  "shared" without having to be explicitly included.

Since its a live mount, you can add dependencies and files to update all your apps that need them simultaneously as an added bonus. However volumes do not work very well when looking to scale your projects beyond your local system and are subject to local tampering.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The bottom line is docker can not auto-resolve dependencies for you and the workarounds for it are far too complicated and/or time consuming to even remotely consider possible for your desired solution since it would be much faster if you were figure out and specify the dependencies yourself. If you want to go out and develop the strategy yourself, go right ahead.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use `inotify`. It's a kernel feature to sniff what is happening on the fly at filesystem level.

Should be something like this:

Use this script `inotify.sh` (don't forget `chmod +x inotify.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
DIRTOMONITOR=/src
apk add --update inotify-tools || $(apt-get update && apt-get install -y inotify-tools)
inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' -e ACCESS $DIRTOMONITOR &
"$@"
```

Run your application, for example:

```
docker run \
  -v $(pwd)/inotify.sh:/inotify.sh \
  --entrypoint /inotify.sh \
  <your-image> \
  node server.js

Watches established.
12:34 /src/ ACCESS server.js             <---------
Server running at http://localhost:4000
```

Each read/written file will be shown as `ACCESS`.

Comment: @Erazihel, what do you think about this approach?

Comment: It sounds kinda good but what if some shared files are used for a specific action only? Does it mean that this specific action has to be performed to be notified by `inotify` that this file has been accessed?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, I can't imagine any other way to know the application's dependencies without knowing the application itself (inspecting package.json, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know if the *application* inside the docker images is using a specific file is to know the application or analyze it's logs from a previous run.

I'll propose another way to solve your problem. It will reduce build time and image size but not necessarily deploy time.

You'll build a base image for all your other images which contains the shared libraries.

```
FROM node:boron
COPY shared /shared
```

And

```
docker build -t erazihel/base:1.0 .
```

You should base all the other images on that image

```
FROM erazihel/base:1.0

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package.json
RUN yarn
RUN yarn release

CMD node release/server.js
```

Since docker images are layered the base image will only exist once on each deployment server and the additional layer each new docker image uses is very small. Build time should also decrease since there is no `COPY/ADD` done for the shared libraries.

There isn't any *cost* in having one big base image since all the following images are much smaller. In fact, you'll likely save space.

Comment: This might be good but the thing is that all the shared files are not especially located in the shared folder and all the Docker images are not Javascript projects.

Comment: You can build one big base image, for all technologies, or a couple different ones for different technologies. And you can add how many different shared folders you wish. This is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

- Build a base image with the shared files.
- Build other images from that base image.

If your 'shared' files are not used in the child image, then the file doesn't belong in the shared folder.

By building a base image with the shared files, you can run the build for each image in its own folder / context without the issues you mention.

Answer (score 0):

`fuser` and `lsof` can be used within the container to monitor open files.

`lsof` does not require you to specify a TARGET FILENAME, so thats better suited your purpose. For usage of `lsof` refer to these examples: [linux-lsof-usage](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-lsof-command)

If you encounter issues with using `lsof` - you can solve this by setting docker into complain mode on the host:
`sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/docker`

References: 
[How to use fuser and lsof](http://www.opensourcerers.org/short-tip-show-processes-accessing-a-file-fuser-lsof/)